# php_solr 1.0.1 for php 5.3+

Tags: php, solr

I'm using solr with php, using php_solr.dll library, when I try to get a response, it fails saying it can not parse results.

So I tried to compile the source code from the latest version in PECL, solr 1.0.1, but I couldn't do, appear errors when compiling.

Do you know or have a php_solr.dll using 1.0.1 for php 5.3 vc9? if you don't do you know or have php_solr version 1.0.1 for any php version?

Thank a lot!.

Comment: Why use an extension for that? Can you just use the [Solr PHP Client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/) library? Or any REST client?

Comment: Because the application is built with it and I want make changes, unfortunately in windows, doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, it's been a year, but maybe someone else is struggling with the same as well...

The Windows extension DLL you needed seems to be available there: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/